# More elegant way to wrap temporaries around incompatible function call

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, tchar

I'm working on Unicode translation of some legacy code. I have some global functions that accept `LPTSTR`. Now some part of the code is strictly ANSI and some are strictly UTF-8. I'm doing something like this:

```
TCHAR szTemp[_countof(wzInputStr)] = {0};
::_tcsncpy(szTemp, CW2T(wzInputStr), _countof(szTemp));
TransformStr(szTemp);
::wcsncpy(wzInputStr, CT2W(szTemp), _countof(wzInputStr));
```

If a function accepts multiple parameters then it is getting tiresome. What could be some better approach to handle this? This does look like a familiar problem.

Comment: Do you mean `UTF-16` instead of `UTF-8`? I ask because  you're dealing with `wchar_t`'s.

Comment: I'm newbie in this, I guess it is UTF-8 encoding only. If it works for WCHAR, I'm good. PS: Please no character-code - offset type solution.

Comment: Depending on the number of functions we’re talking about, I would say either write your own wrappers, or create a class that can hold the temporaries and pass them on to the function call

Comment: You can write a `CInOut` that does the equivalent of a `CW2T` on construction and the equivalent of a `CT2W` on destruction. Then it would be `TransformStr(CInOut(wzInputStr));`

Comment: I was thinking about the same and already looking in atlconv.h for hints.:) I also found this page to be interesting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn059-using-mfc-mbcs-unicode-conversion-macros?view=msvc-170